# Setup gRPC TLS server auth with only CA certificate

Tags: go, ssl, grpc

I want to setup gRPC TLS server auth using only CA certificate, e.g. `CA.cert` and `CA.key` on the server side, and `CA.cert` on the client to authenticate the server.

So I dont want to generate server certificate and sign it with the CA.

Of course this is only for development convenience.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

For development convenience, the self-signed certificate could be used

- Generate the certificate

Here are some steps to generate the self-signed certificate

```bash
# 1. Generate CA's private key and self-signed certificate
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -days 365 -nodes -keyout ca-key.pem -out ca-cert.pem -subj "C=US/ST=NJ/O=CA, Inc"

echo "CA's self-signed certificate"
openssl x509 -in ca-cert.pem -noout -text

# 2. Generate web server's private key and certificate signing request (CSR)
openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -keyout server-key.pem -out server-req.pem -subj "C=US/ST=NJ/O=CA, Inc"

# 3. Use CA's private key to sign web server's CSR and get back the signed certificate
openssl x509 -req -in server-req.pem -days 60 -CA ca-cert.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -CAcreateserial -out server-cert.pem -extfile server-ext.cnf

echo "Server's signed certificate"
openssl x509 -in server-cert.pem -noout -text
```

- TLS on server side

```golang
func loadTLSCredentials() (credentials.TransportCredentials, error) {
    // Load server's certificate and private key
    serverCert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("cert/server-cert.pem", "cert/server-key.pem")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Create the credentials and return it
    config := &tls.Config{
        Certificates: []tls.Certificate{serverCert},
        ClientAuth:   tls.NoClientCert,
    }

    return credentials.NewTLS(config), nil
}

...

    tlsCredentials, err := loadTLSCredentials()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("cannot load TLS credentials: ", err)
    }

    grpcServer := grpc.NewServer(
        grpc.Creds(tlsCredentials),
        grpc.UnaryInterceptor(interceptor.Unary()),
        grpc.StreamInterceptor(interceptor.Stream()),
    )
```

- TLS on client side

```golang
func loadTLSCredentials() (credentials.TransportCredentials, error) {
    // Load certificate of the CA who signed server's certificate
    pemServerCA, err := ioutil.ReadFile("cert/ca-cert.pem")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    certPool := x509.NewCertPool()
    if !certPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(pemServerCA) {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to add server CA's certificate")
    }

    // Create the credentials and return it
    config := &tls.Config{
        RootCAs:      certPool,
    }

    return credentials.NewTLS(config), nil
}

....

    tlsCredentials, err := loadTLSCredentials()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("cannot load TLS credentials: ", err)
    }

    cc1, err := grpc.Dial(*serverAddress, grpc.WithTransportCredentials(tlsCredentials))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("cannot dial server: ", err)
    }

    ...

    cc2, err := grpc.Dial(
        *serverAddress,
        grpc.WithTransportCredentials(tlsCredentials),
        grpc.WithUnaryInterceptor(interceptor.Unary()),
        grpc.WithStreamInterceptor(interceptor.Stream()),
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("cannot dial server: ", err)
    }
```

Source: [How to secure gRPC connection with SSL/TLS in Go](https://dev.to/techschoolguru/how-to-secure-grpc-connection-with-ssl-tls-in-go-4ph)

---

Also you could refer to the [gRPC tls samples](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/tree/master/examples/features/encryption) under [grpc-go](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go) repo